# Where to put non coding challenges?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have an idea for a question as shown here https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2322/19894 but it is not really something that has todo with coding, it is more redefine language tokens.

Where should I post this kind of questions? This for example is really fun to do, you could e.g. translate C++ to German or French or even Klingon ^^

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, that would be off-topic here. The site is called *Programming* Puzzles and Code Golf. If we started accepting things that weren't programming, pretty soon we'd get language challenges and math challenges and cooking challenges and all sorts of off-topic stuff.

Just because something would be really fun to do doesn't mean that makes it any more on-topic. I like playing piano, and other people do too. But that doesn't mean I can post a piano puzzle or something here.

Comment: What I wanted to know, was where shall I put this kind of question here on SE? The addon with the part that it is fun to do was more like, "Hey, I would like people to know about this, but where to post it?" ;)

Comment: @Knerd, you could post the question on a personal blog and then drop a mention of it into chat.